# what's the trick behind python's any() function?

Tags: python, performance

One of the [pycon2011 talks](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-how-dropbox-did-it-and-how-python-helped-4896698) shared this `any()` function trick; the explanation was that the loop is in C.

Could someone explain more about it? What is the trick behind it and is there any other use cases?

```
>>> import itertools, hashlib, time
>>> _md5 = hashlib.md5()
>>> def run():
...   for i in itertools.repeat('foo', 10000000):
...     _md5.update(i)
... 
>>> a = time.time(); run(); time.time() -a
3.9815599918365479
>>> _md5 = hashlib.md5()
>>> def run():
...   any(itertools.imap(_md5.update, itertools.repeat('foo', 10000000)))
... 
>>> a = time.time(); run(); time.time() -a
2.1475138664245605
>>>
```

Comment: perhaps if you posted a link to the video.

Comment: http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-how-dropbox-did-it-and-how-python-helped-4896698

Comment: Possibly duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012611/any-function-in-python-with-a-callback

Comment: you don't need `any`, in fact `filter(_md5.update, itertools.repeat('foo', 10000000))` would be even faster.

Comment: @tomasz could you please tell me why it is even faster?

Comment: @alexband, it's not faster than `any` per se, but you don't need `imap`, hence less operations required.

Answer (score 4):

itertools.imap creates a lazy list which contains the function to be evaluated (md5) and it's argument ('foo' string).  The md5 calls are  not evaluated at this point but prepared along with their arguments (I think they are called thunks).  When you then pass this iterator to any function, it goes through all the elements evaluating them.  This happens faster than explicit Python evaluation from the first program, because `any` is implemented in C and everything happens in the C library code without returning to the interpreter after each iterator element.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "trick" per se; [running compiled C code is faster than running Python bytecode](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html).