# Is there a function for “forall” in python?

Tags: python, forall

I am trying to write a code that finds the multiplicative identity of a finite ring with addition modulo n and multiplication modulo n as the operations. Basically it should return that element e such that e*y%n=y for all y in R

What I have tried is the following:

```
U=[e for e in R for y in R if e*y%10==y]
Unity=[x for x in U if U.count(x)==len(R)]
if Unity:
   print(“The given ring has multiplicative identity”,Unity[0])
else: 
   print(“The given ring has no multiplicative identity)
```

The problem with this is that the list U is not taking only that e which works for all y in R. That is the reason I’m creating another list that counts the number of times an e has occurred in U.

I was wondering if I could avoid having to create the second list by instead using some inbuilt function that works as “for all”? I checked online and found the .all() function but I am not sure how to use it here.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd use Python for this, rather than any of the several popular dedicated maths languages.

Comment: It’s one of the weird aspects of our mathematics syllabus. We have to learn python as a programming language and learn to write python codes based on the things we learn in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has an `all` function, which does most of what you want. Rather than having two nested `for` clauses in your list comprehension, you'll want a separate generator expression for the `y` loop, inside of `all`:

```
U = [e for e in R if all(e*y%10=y for y in R)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. I think there has to be a double equal to sign in the syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an iterable to [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012631/11323371)

```py
U = [e for e in R for y in R if e*y%10==y]
```

Then pass `U` to `all`

```py
all(U.count(x)==len(R) for x in U)
```

This works as a generator would, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012631/11323371)

`all` returns `True` if *all* elements are `True`